# ImageIcon do not update for a new image with the same URL

Tags: java, swing

I would like to use JLabel(Icon) to show a Image which is from my website(http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/java_pic/test.jpg).
And I have a refresh button to new a new JLabel and ImageIcon(in order to get the newest image)
The program run successfully...but when I upload a new image to override the old one(http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/java_pic/test.jpg), I press the refresh button... nothing happened!
I restart my program... and the new image now appears... why?
Shouldn't it reload the image from website when I new a ImageIcon again?

```
public void refresh(){
    URL iconUri = null;
    iconUri = new URL("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/java_pic/test.jpg");
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(iconUri);
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(imageIcon);
    frame.add(imageLabel);
    ...
    ...
}
```

when I click the refresh button, it would call the refresh()...why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image is cached.  Flush to clear the cache:

```
imageIcon.getImage().flush();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works! Another question is that could I flush the imageIcon immediately after I "new JLabel(imageIcon);"?