# Can´t get image icon to update

Tags: java, swing

I have an application that gets a random image from a website. I have a JFrame with a JPanel in it. The image is added into a JLabel. 
My problem is that the new image won´t show. After I choose the "New Image" option in the menu bar I want the old image to be replaced with the new one.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel imagePanel;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem menuItemNew;
    private JLabel label;


    public GUI(String title) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());            
        newImage();                 
        initComponents();             
        setSize(600, 400);     
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        initMenu();                   
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {        
        scroll = new JScrollPane(imagePanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);              
    } 

    private void initMenu() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menuItemNew = new JMenuItem("New image");           
        menu.add(menuItemNew);              
        menuItemNew.addActionListener(this);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (e.getSource().equals(menuItemNew)) {
            newImage();                   
         }   
    }


    private void newImage() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        URL imageURL = new URL("http://xxxxxxx");
        BufferedImage buffImg = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(buffImg);
        label = new JLabel("", icon, JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setIcon(icon);
        imagePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        imagePanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        revalidate();    
        repaint();
    }
 }
```

Comment: If the URL is the same, this is probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885696/imageicon-do-not-update-for-a-new-image-with-the-same-url

Comment: I have tried icon.getImage().flush(); but nothing changes. I'm not sure though exactly where in the code to put it. I have tried a few different places (for example after repaint();).
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Put it right after creating the `ImageIcon`.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work.... I earlier moved around that piece of code, but it seems like it makes no difference.
Do you have any more suggestions of what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you recreate your imagePanel, it never gets associated with the scroll pane.

The easiest way to fix this is to move the imagePanel and label creation up into initComponents, making label a field then in newImage()

```
private JLabel imageLabel;
private void newImage() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    ...
    imageLabel.setIcon(icon); 
    revalidate();    
    repaint();
}
```

Also, as the next problem you will almost certainly have is that the random web images are not the right size, I highly recommend the image resizing utility methods provided by [filthyrichclients](https://java.net/projects/filthyrichclients/sources/svn/content/trunk/StaticEffects/BlurryReflection/src/GraphicsUtilities.java?raw=true).

I actually highly recommend the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132413930) as well, as it was one of the few books that actually demonstrated the power of Swing...

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem!
I moved the creation of imagePanel and label to initComponents, and that made it work (after moving the call to initComponents() above the call to newImage() in the constructor.
You made my day, I've been struggling with this the whole day. Now I can continue with the application. Thanks again!