# IconImage or g.drawImage to display image on jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

As I am new to Java `Swing`, once I wanted to create a `JFrame` and capture frames from the webcam connected through the USB and then display the contents on the `JFrame`. To achieve this I read some posts and as the post suggested, I created a `JLabel` and every frame captured from the webcam I converted it to image and created `IconImage` and added it to the `JLabel` and finally add the `JLabel` to the `JFrame`. The result was that only the first captured image from the webcam was taken and added to the `JFrame` and the image on the `JFrame` never changes, and that is not what I want.

After searching and reading I found that, to do so, I have to create a class that extends `JPanel` and implement the method `paintcomponent()` and every frame I capture from the webcam is passed it to that class that extends `JPanel` and display the image using `g.drawImage()`

My question is, why can't I change the image frequntly using `IconImage`? 
Is `g.drawImage()` is the only way to display images on `JPanel`?

Comment: Use a combination of a Swing `Timer` and either a `JLabel` or `Image` to renderer the images.  The `Timer` acts as a means to update the UI.  Both `JLabel` and `paintComponent` has pros and cons but both can achieve the same result.  Which you would choose will depend on what it is you hope to achieve with the images.  If you just want to display them, the `JLabel` is simpler

Comment: The main problem is most likely that by default, images in an `ImageIcon` are cached. In order to really update the image in an `ImageIcon` (that is, if the image changes, but the filename remains the same), you have to **flush** the cache, by calling `imageIcon.getImage().flush();`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885696/imageicon-do-not-update-for-a-new-image-with-the-same-url